# Windows keeps adding Xbox icon to the taskbar

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, xbox360

Anytime my computer turns off or I change the user, the Xbox icon keeps showing up... how can I remove it for good?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to solve it, I followed the next steps

1. [Windows Key]+R and write `%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Shell`.
2. Edit the file named `LayoutModification.xml`.
3. Delete the following line that has the terms `taskbar` and `Microsoft.Xbox.App` (in my case, line 197)

Before deleting...

[image]

After deleting...

[image]

4. At last, if you haven't removed the app from the Taskbar too, do it now and restart the computer.

**Reference**: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/xbox-app-will-not-stay-off-of-taskbar/e430a077-39fb-4537-9bac-41890c7dee9c?auth=1